# Плавное движение объекта в python?

Tags: python

Как на python реализовать плавное движение спрайта pygame в координаты x, y алгоритмом?

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.update()
x = 100
y = 100
class Player:
    def slip(x, y):
        pass
```

Comment: Какого объекта, о чём речь?

Comment: Объект это спрайт pygame